# How to search single value in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have 2 docs in elasticsearch:

```
{"_id": "1", "a": "123"}
{"_id": "2", "a": ["123", "456"]}
```

Then I query like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "term": {
                    "a": "123"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I got:

```
{"_id": "1", "a": "123"}
{"_id": "2", "a": ["123", "456"]}
```

I **know** elasticsearch natively support multi value filed so both of them are presented.
But I only want the first entry, whose id is "1":

```
{"_id": "1", "a": "123"}
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using script

You can use script to return documents where array size is 1. If document with single value is not present then it "will not" return documents with multiple values. It is not possible to get next minimum size  matching document. This will have to be handled in client side

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "a": "123"
          }
        },
        {
          "script": {
            "script": "if(doc['a.keyword'].size()==1) return true;"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow... that's tricky, what if I have two docs with the same filed: "a": "123"? I want both of them but the solution depends on I know the size of results